# How to disable the treeviewitem background color change?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, treeviewitem, lost-focus

I have a following problem: I have two treeview controls in my WPF app and when I click on one of the items in first tree and then click on one of the items in second tree, then the item in first tree changes it backgroud color. I tried to change the background color in the multitrigger

```
 <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
  <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
  <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
 </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
```

for template property but with no effect. How can I disable this behaviour ? Here Is my sample window code(Im not changing the treeview control in code behind)

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflowTests.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBorder" Color="#828790"/>
    <Style x:Key="TreeViewStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ListBorder}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="_tv_scrollviewer_" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CanContentScroll="false" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}">
                            <ItemsPresenter/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="CanContentScroll" TargetName="_tv_scrollviewer_" Value="true"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="TreeViewItemFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.Static.Checked.Fill" Color="#FF595959"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.Static.Checked.Stroke" Color="#FF262626"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.MouseOver.Stroke" Color="#FF1BBBFA"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.MouseOver.Fill" Color="Transparent"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.MouseOver.Checked.Stroke" Color="#FF262626"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.MouseOver.Checked.Fill" Color="#FF595959"/>
    <PathGeometry x:Key="TreeArrow" Figures="M0,0 L0,6 L6,0 z"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.Static.Fill" Color="Transparent"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.Static.Stroke" Color="#FF989898"/>
    <Style x:Key="ExpandCollapseToggleStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="16"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="16"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Border Background="Transparent" Height="16" Padding="5,5,5,5" Width="16">
                        <Path x:Name="ExpandPath" Data="{StaticResource TreeArrow}" Fill="{StaticResource TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.Static.Fill}" Stroke="{StaticResource TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.Static.Stroke}">
                            <Path.RenderTransform>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="135" CenterY="3" CenterX="3"/>
                            </Path.RenderTransform>
                        </Path>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="RenderTransform" TargetName="ExpandPath">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="180" CenterY="3" CenterX="3"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.Static.Checked.Fill}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.Static.Checked.Stroke}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.MouseOver.Stroke}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.MouseOver.Fill}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.MouseOver.Checked.Stroke}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.MouseOver.Checked.Fill}"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="TreeViewItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1,0,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItemFocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="19" Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander" ClickMode="Press" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{DynamicResource ToggleButtonStyle1}"/>
                        <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Column="1" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ItemsHost" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Expander" Value="Hidden"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger> 
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ToggleButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="16"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="16"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Border Background="Transparent" Height="16" Padding="5,5,5,5" Width="16">
                        <Path x:Name="ExpandPath" Data="{StaticResource TreeArrow}" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HotTrackBrushKey}}" Stroke="{StaticResource TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.Static.Stroke}">
                            <Path.RenderTransform>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="135" CenterY="3" CenterX="3"/>
                            </Path.RenderTransform>
                        </Path>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="RenderTransform" TargetName="ExpandPath">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="180" CenterY="3" CenterX="3"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.Static.Checked.Fill}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.Static.Checked.Stroke}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.MouseOver.Stroke}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.MouseOver.Fill}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.MouseOver.Checked.Stroke}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.MouseOver.Checked.Fill}"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TreeView x:Name="XX" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Style="{DynamicResource TreeViewStyle1}" Background="#7B898C">
        <TreeViewItem Header="XXXX_1" Style="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle1}">
            <TreeViewItem Header="XXXX_2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>

    <TreeView x:Name="XX2" Margin="10,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Style="{DynamicResource TreeViewStyle1}" Background="#7B898C">
        <TreeViewItem Header="XXXX_3" Style="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle1}">
            <TreeViewItem Header="XXXX_4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only thing I can see wrong in the code you've posted is your `Trigger`'s `Setter` sets both `Background` and `Foreground` to the same color `{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}`

You could also maybe try setting the `MultiTrigger` condition as `Selector.IsSelectionActive` to be explicit:

I tried your posted code with these changes (Works fine for me in Windows-8):

```
<MultiTrigger>
  <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                Value="true" />
    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive"
                Value="false" />
  </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
  <Setter TargetName="Bd"
          Property="Background"
          Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
  <Setter Property="Foreground"
          Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}" />
</MultiTrigger>
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:**

Your only setting `Style` for the Top `TreeViewItem` as `TreeViewItemStyle1`. Hence the default `Style` gets applied to the Child `TreeViewItem`'s which don't specify a `Style`. If you want it to apply automatically to all `TreeViewItem`'s just remove the Style Key in declaration and it should be applied automatically based on the `TargetType`

Comment: Thank you. problem solved. Two things are the key here, first one is Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" and second to be sure that every treeview item has the defined style.